# how to calculate minimum distance of a code minus a subcode

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups, coding-theory, gap

I have a linear binary code $C$ with generators $(G_1,\cdots,G_a,G_{a+1},\cdots G_k)$.

$C$ has a subcode $C_a$ with generators $(G_1,\cdots,G_a)$.

I'd like to get the minimum **weight** of all codewords in $C$ that are **not** in $C_a$.

[Edit : minimum **distance** in original question changed to minimum **weight**]

Is there a way to get this without listing elements?

I'm tagging abelian groups and GAP since this can be viewed in a group setting too : I think this translates to looking at cosets of $C_a$ in $C$ and taking a representative (or "leader") of minimum weight.

An example for the Jyrki's answer : first 8 rows are for $C_a$ (so $r=2$)

```
[[1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
 [1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1]]
```

$d_{min}(C)=4$ but $d_{min}(C-C_a)$ is known to be $6$ using other methods (brute force listing of elements). Note that this code is "degenerate" : it doesn't have unique columns (21 unique columns out of 27). The codes I tried that Jyrki's answer works for have unique columns.

Comment: By row reduction I got that $$c=\{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0\}$$ is a word of weight four in the code $C_a$. Let $$x=\{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1\}$$ be the last generator, so $x\in C\setminus C_a$. Therefore $x+c$ is not in $C_a$ either. And the Hamming distance $d(x,x+c)=w(c)=4$, so $d_{min}(C\setminus C_a)$ is four also.

Comment: You mention "brute force listing". Just to make sure: you did do a double loop on it, didn't you? It is perfectly possible that $C\setminus C_a$ does not contain any words of weight four. Its minimum distance is still four though. The minimum distance and the minimum weight don't necessarily agree on non-linear codes such as $C\setminus C_a$.

Comment: what you have is correct, but what I'm after is $d(0,x+c)=6$ not $d(x,x+c)=4$;

Comment: I was using weight and distance interchangeably; it is in fact the weight that I'm after. I edited the question to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately that makes my observations rather meaningless. No worries, though:-)

Comment: Not at all...your answer works for distance which has value in its own right.

Answer (score 1):

A reminder: In general the question whether a linear code has non-zero words of Hamming weight below a given threshold is a difficult one. Alex Vardy proved it to be in one of those nasty complexity classes (NP-hard, NP-complete, ..., I don't know for sure). GAP/GUAVA can work with small codes easily enough, and the weight enumerators of some classes of codes with a rigid algebraic structure are known, but in general the outlook is grim.

---

The following observation can be done though. The result is that the minimum distance of $C\setminus C_a$ is equal to the minimum distance of one of the codes. The choice depends on the codimension that I denote by
by $r=\dim C-\dim C_a$, so $r=k-a$.

- If $r=1$, then the complement $C\setminus C_a$ is just a single coset of $C_a$. As translation by a fixed vector is an isometry of the Hamming space, the distance distribution of $C\setminus C_a$ is identical to that of $C_a$. In particular, $d_{min}(C\setminus C_a)=d_{min}(C_a)$.
- If $r>1$, then $d_{min}(C\setminus C_a)=d_{min}(C)$. This can be shown as follows. Let $c\in C$ be a word of minimal (non-zero) Hamming weight $d_{min}(C)$. There are at least four cosets of $C_a$ in $C$. This means that there exists a coset $x+C_a\neq C_a$ such that the coset $c+x+C_a$ isn't equal to $C_a$ either. After all, translation by the word $c$ either permutes the cosets of $C_a$ in 2-cycles, or maps all the cosets to themselves (the latter case happens when $c\in C_a$). But both words $x,c+x\notin C_a$, and their distance is equal to the weight of $c$, that is, equal to $d_{min}(C)$. Obviously the minimum distance cannot be lower than that so we are done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Somehow this doesn't match my "experimental" results. There are codes ($r>1$) where $d_{min}(C-Ca) \neq d_{min}(C)$. I use different algorithms to cross check with the brute force listing of elements as a final check. My examples are large codes; I'll look for a small example to post.

Comment: I edited the answer with an example. For degenerate codes more than one error can have the same syndrome. The example is degenerate; this could be a clue.